# Why we can't reliably test for palindromes on one pass

Tags: string, algorithm, memory, palindrome, automata

I came across the concept of "palindrome". I try to understand by reading through wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome#Computation_theory

The paragraph caughts my attention

> This means that it is impossible for a computer with a finite amount
>   of memory to reliably test for palindromes on one pass.

I thought to test whether a given string is "palindrome" is pretty straight forward? I came out a quick code.

```
public class Utils {
    private static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX = "[\\s!,]";

    private static String removeSpecialCharacters(String string) {
        return string.replaceAll(SPECIAL_CHARACTERS_REGEX, "");
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(String string) {
        String str = string.toLowerCase();
        str = removeSpecialCharacters(str);

        if (str.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        int head = 0;
        int tail = str.length() - 1;
        while (head < tail) {
            char h = str.charAt(head);
            char t = str.charAt(tail);

            if (h != t) {
                return false;
            }

            head++;
            tail--;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

It seems to work fine at first glance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + Utils.isPalindrome(s)); // false

    s = "1";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + Utils.isPalindrome(s)); // true

    s = "12";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + Utils.isPalindrome(s)); // false

    s = "123";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + Utils.isPalindrome(s)); // false

    s = "taco cat";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + Utils.isPalindrome(s)); // true

    s = "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + Utils.isPalindrome(s)); // true

    s = "Amor, Roma";
    System.out.println(s + " -> " + Utils.isPalindrome(s)); // true
}
```

If so, may I know why the wikipedia states that it is impossible to test for palindromes on one pass? Am I overlook something?

Comment: May I know which test case produces wrong result?

Comment: Is `abcdedcba` one of a palindromes, which without a meaning? Can a program tells it is a meaningful sentence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not checking whether a string already in memory is a palindrome. If you can get the string into memory, the check can be done easily, but you've already used up the one pass by reading the string into memory, so the check is the second pass.

But that will only work if the entire string fits into memory. Since the premise is that memory is finite, it means you cannot verify whether strings which are longer than the capacity of memory are palindromes, which is what the sentence you quote is saying.

By contrast, there are lots of checks you can do with finite memory on arbitrarily long strings. For example, you can check whether the string's length is divisible by 5. You can check if every `a` in the string is immediately followed by a `b`. In general, you can check if the string matches any regular expression (here, I mean regular expression in the mathematical sense, as opposed to the patterns recognized by "regular expression" libraries.) But since you cannot describe the set of all palindromes using a regular expression, you cannot verify in a single pass that an arbitrarily long string is a palindrome, using only a finite amount of memory.

Answer (score 2):

You just missed the first line before the referred line which says :-

> In the automata theory, a set of all palindromes in a given alphabet
>   is a typical example of a language that is context-free, but not
>   regular.

Here, they are talking about listing all possible palindromes on a given alphabe.

Let's talk about the binary alphabet,A={0,1}. Considering the language -> The number of palindromes on the alphabet A. There can be an infinite number of palindrome strings like 1,0,11,00,101,111,...and so on.

In case of the palindrome languages, ***it is at least not possible to get the idea of middle element and keep that in memory(track), in the same single pass, in finite memory systems***. For that you need to keep track of all sorts of characters of a string being evaluated, and how will you determine the incoming characters are reversed of the one you've visited, only in a single pass in a finite-memory system?

Wikipedia also states :-

> In addition, the set of palindromes may not be reliably tested by a
>   deterministic pushdown automaton. When reading a palindrome from
>   left-to-right, it is, in essence, impossible to locate the "middle"
>   until the entire word has been read completely.

Such a language which consists of all such strings can't be evaluated in a single pass in the finite-memory system,and hence,because of the finite-memory limitation, can't be a regular language(a regular language can be defined as a language recognised by a finite automaton---**this language can't be recognised in a finite-memory system because finite-memory systems can't have multiple passes**). So, the language can't evaluate all those sets of strings for palindromes. Hence, it is clearly an example of a **finite-memory system**.

This question reverts back to one of the famous questions of Automata theory :-

For a language E, `E = {0^i 1^j | i > j}` is not regular. And,hence it can't be proved on a machine with a finite memory.You need pumping lemma theorem to prove that the given language is not regular. Then, you will need to put back pushdown-automata here. But,that too has got its limits(lets not talk about it here)

Also, the next line clearly intends to say that modern computers with huge memory and latest techniques involving many passes will easily achieve the same--->

> (For practical purposes with modern computers, this limitation would
>   apply only to incredibly long letter-sequences.) 
>   // Again when the memory exhausts in the modern computers while
>   checking for palindromes.

Comment: They are not talking about listing all possible palindromes in a given alphabetical string.  They are in fact talking about recognising whether a given string is a palindrome, if we can only access the string in the way that a finite automaton does -- that is, by reading one character at a time, storing only the current state (an integer of bounded size), and without knowing the input length until we hit the end.

Comment: The set of all palindromes *in a given alphabet* (what the Wikipedia page is talking about) is very different from the set of all palindromes *in a given alphabetical string* (what you're talking about).  The set of all palindromes in the alphabet {A, B} is A, B, AA, BB, ABA, BAB, ABBA, ..., i.e., an infinite set of words, i.e., a language.  (Admittedly it would be clearer for the Wikipedia page to write "the set of all palindromes *on* (or *over*) a given alphabet".)  The set of all palindromes in the string DEFFEDDE is just a finite set: DEFFED, EFFE, FF, EDDE, DD (plus all the 1-char ones).

Comment: @j_random_hacker- I agree with you,I am making the necessary edit. And, to be truthful, I meant to say the same, but,don't know how I confused. And, the other lines in my answer convey my intent,,those lines which are talking about automata.

Comment: On what basis do you claim "Such a language which consists of all such strings can't be a regular language"?  I would interpret this sentence to mean "Any language similar to this one, i.e. any language that contains an infinite number of strings, can't be a regular language" -- but this is false.  Many regular languages contain an infinite number of strings.

Comment: I don't know what "For a given language E, E = {0^i 1^j | i > j} is not regular." means.  Do you just mean "The language E = {0^i 1^j | i > j} is not regular"? I see two problems: (1) I don't see how this is related to the language of palindromes; (2) I don't know if the statement is actually true or false. (If it's true, then this is not obvious: E contains *all* strings with more 0s at the front than 1s at the end, and the usual way to apply the pumping lemma just lets you add more 0s at the front, which will not force the contradiction needed to conclude that it is not regular.)

Comment: "And,hence it can't be proved on a machine with a finite memory." -- this sentence does not make sense, as far as I can tell.  Do you mean "recognised" instead of "proved"?  Then the sentence would logically follow from non-regularity.  BTW I appreciate your fixes so far and will eventually +2 if you fix the problems that remain :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker-First of all, this E language is a famous language for example of a non-regular language in "Theory of Computation". Having infinite strings in a language isn't a problem, I haven't mentioned one. I think you misunderstood that line. To be more clear--->`Actually, to traverse those palindromes in a single pass and keep track of the palindromes isn't possible just like traversing the given language E for format of all )00000...111111... kind of strings`. In this way they are synonymous.

Comment: @j_random_hacker-Talking about the Wikipedia Article, in case of the palindromes language, it is at least not possible to get the idea of middle element and keep that in memory **in a single pass** in limited memory systems. For that you need to keep track of all sorts of characters of a string being evaluated, and how will you determine the incoming characters are reversed of the one you've visited, **only in a single pass** in a finite-memory system.

Comment: @j_random_hacker-In addition, the set of palindromes may not be reliably tested by a deterministic pushdown automaton. When reading a palindrome from left-to-right, it is, in essence, impossible to locate the "middle" until the entire word has been read completely.

Comment: If my interpretation of "Such a language which consists of all such strings can't be a regular language" is incorrect, then what do you mean by it?  Most people will interpret it the way I have.

Comment: @j_random_hacker-And, I also am very thankful to you for providing me with the opportunity to help me improving my answer. It seems now I can also like answers like an experienced person like you, who keeps track of all points for clarity and exactness. Anyways, I am very much thankful to you for providing this much time of yours for helping me improve my --- one of the best answer(in my view) . Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your attitude, thanks :)  It's improved enough now that I've dropped my -1. I'm still puzzled why you bring up the language E = {0^i 1^j | i > j} at all -- from your comment, I infer that you mean it to be another example of a language which cannot be recognised by a finite automaton, but in that case you should say so in the answer, e.g. "Another well-known example of a simple language that cannot be recognised by a computer with finite memory is the language E = {0^i 1^j | i > j}".

Comment: Actually, I am from a non-native English speaking country(India). There does exist enough such problems to explain your sentence to other(especially to native English speakers). Next, actually, those are synonymous because both can't be tracked in a single pass, and in a finite memory system(finite memory system can't have multiple passes). This was what I meant in the proper way

Comment: BTW, as I mentioned earlier, you simply can't write "For a given language E, E = {0^i 1^j | i > j} is not regular."  That's like writing "For a given value X, X = 42 is not a prime number".  The latter should obviously be simply "X = 42 is not a prime number", and the former should be "The language E = {0^i 1^j | i > j} is not regular": we only write "given" when *we don't know* what it's exact value is yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79170/discussion-between-shekhar-suman-and-j-random-hacker).

Comment: Your English is very good, and I'm impressed by anyone who can speak more than one language!  Nevertheless I can't upvote an answer if I can't understand parts of it.  Although you've explained it in the comments to me, it's still not clear to a reader *of your answer* why you mention this other language E.  (You go so far as to call E "the original question in Automata theory" -- but surely, if there is such an important question, it is about whether *any given* language is regular or not -- not whether E in particular is.)

Answer (score 0):

If the string has length n, your code uses O(log(n)) storage (the indices `head` and `tail` need O(log(n)) bits). Thus your program needs an unbounded amount of memory to be able to test arbitrarily long strings.

The application of complexity analysis to real code is difficult and usually not theoretically sound: obviously in Java `head` and `tail` are ints and 32 bits long each. But complexity analysis deals with arbitrarily large inputs and not just the large-enough-for-all-practical-purposes that real programming languages support and the difference can be hard to reconcile (as here).